# How to add margin bottom in Tittle ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to know how to add bottom margin to my title in ChartJS to prevent Datalabels from overlapping the title, thanks.

you can view the graph in that link
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTZlY.png)

I use:

- ChartJS
- ChartJS Datalabels

This is my code

```
//chart por rango de edad
var ctx_age_range = document.getElementById('chart_age_range');
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx_age_range, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["<20", "20-29", "30-39", "40-55", ">56"],
        datasets: [{
          label: "Cantidad",
          backgroundColor: ["#47b3d5", "#47b3d5","#47b3d5","#47b3d5","#47b3d5"],
          data: [0.32,34.55,34.79,25.32,5.02]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false,
         },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'CASOS POR RANGO DE EDAD',
            fontSize:15,
            color:"black"
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {display: false},
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 1,
                    min: 0,
                    fontSize:12
                },
                barPercentage: 0.8,
                categoryPercentage: 1,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: false,
                },
                gridLines: {display: false,drawBorder:false},
                ticks:{
                    display:false,
                },
            }]
        },
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                display: true,
                align: 'end',
                anchor: 'end',
                formatter: function(value, ctx) {
                    return value+'%';
                },
                color:'black',
                font:{
                    size: 11
                }
            }
        }
                        
    }
});
```

I would like to know how add margin bottom to the title or how to add margin/padding top top of graphic.

Comment: Could you please include your code with issue reproducable?

Comment: yes, i do. I add the code in description. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `padding` property on the `title` option to achieve that:

```js
var ctx_age_range = document.getElementById('chart_age_range');
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx_age_range, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["<20", "20-29", "30-39", "40-55", ">56"],
        datasets: [{
          label: "Cantidad",
          backgroundColor: ["#47b3d5", "#47b3d5","#47b3d5","#47b3d5","#47b3d5"],
          data: [0.32,34.55,34.79,25.32,5.02]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false,
         },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'CASOS POR RANGO DE EDAD',
            fontSize:15,
            color:"black",
            padding: 30
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {display: false},
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 1,
                    min: 0,
                    fontSize:12
                },
                barPercentage: 0.8,
                categoryPercentage: 1,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: false,
                },
                gridLines: {display: false,drawBorder:false},
                ticks:{
                    display:false,
                },
            }]
        },
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                display: true,
                align: 'end',
                anchor: 'end',
                formatter: function(value, ctx) {
                    return value+'%';
                },
                color:'black',
                font:{
                    size: 11
                }
            }
        }
                        
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart_age_range" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is with the plugin ChartJS Datalabels,  the number is overlapping the title, therefore i would like add margin top to the chart.

Comment: @JoelFernandez just updated my code and answer, sorry I missed including datalables lib before.

Comment: Awesome! Glad could help, don't forget to mark it as an answer!